# Particle Normal-tangent option

Tags: particles

So I've downloaded this free carpet asset so I could learn on it how to make a realistic carpet, but I don't really get how does Normal-tangent in Rotation option affects direction of carpet strings. I can't find any thing on google, nor youtube. Only thing I realised is that the unwrapped polygons look really weird and when I UV unwrap the mesh of the carpet again, strings are no longer affected by the tangent value. How do I achieve the same results as in the asset if I wanted to make it from scratch?

[image]

Here's a link to the file:
[image]

Comment: Without more details, we don't know either! Suggest you add a link to the Blend file in your question: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @JohnEason I've just included a link. I want to make exact same carpet but in square on the entire floor in my room design and I have no idea how to achieve similar strings align

Comment: Okay so I've just found out if I move and rotate vertexes in the UV window in a random direction it creates a similar effect as I wanted, but I bet there's some simplier option to make that, instead of manually manipulating it.

Comment: Sounds like a job for python or maybe geometry nodes. I'm not familiar with either I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to try Geo Nodes it's pretty straight forward...

[image]

in this example i have two set of noise texture, the first one influence the instances rotation (particles), the second one twist the hair.
First subdivide the mesh in order to have the good amount  of faces then put a point on each faces, then instance on point (this is the first part of the first line).

You have to choose the type of instances, here of course I chose a Bezier Segment that I subdivide (the four other node make the hair pointy, I like pointy things, but it's not our main purpose).

[image]

Now that this instance is created we get bake to the first line : the first noise will rotate the instances. It's time to transform instances in to curves (Realize Instances)

[image]

Now came the tricky part : twist the tip of the hair and how to select it.
The end point selection will exactly do that select points that will be influenced by the second noise.

[image]

But in order to be more precise the twist will be controlled by anther factor the curve length in fact the curve length will directly affect the amount of noise via a float curve in the scale vector.

[image]

Then the end part you will transform the curves in to mesh, with the profile you choose, an arc.
the last are self evident, smooth, material and join geometry in order to see the "base" of the hair set.

Leave a comment if you need more explanations.Bye.

[image]